# Python extract subset of key values from List of Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I Need help in extracting subset of key, values from original list of dictionaries.
I was able to get the key value pairs but unable to save them to new dictionary, when I print my new dictionary all I can get is the last key value pair but not all the subset key, value pairs

```
    list1=[{'t1':43, 't2':45, 't3':56, 't4':59, 't5':45, 't6':31}, {'t1':3, 't2':5, 't3':5, 't4':9}, {'t1':47, 't2':59, 't3':86, 't4':5}]
    myks=['t1','t3']
    newlist={}
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in list1[i].keys():
            if j in myks:
                print (j,list1[i][j])
                newlist={j: list1[i][j]}
                
    print(newlist)
```

Output I am getting:

```
t1 43
t3 56
t1 3
t3 5
t1 47
t3 86
{'t3': 86}
```

expected: `{'t1':43, t3:56, 't1':3, 't3':5, 't3':86}`
Please let me know where i am doing wrong and help to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: a `dict` can't contain a key more than once. What you are expecting is impossible to get with a `dict`.

Comment: Also, you're assigning newdict to a new dictionary with single value each time j is in myks. You need to associate a key to a value (newdict[j] = list[i][j]).

Comment: Thanks,, checking your option as well , as original solution is not inserting duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your expected output is not possible, as all dictionary keys must be unique. You could add all matching values to nested lists to have them be accessible:

```py
list1=[{'t1':43, 't2':45, 't3':56, 't4':59, 't5':45, 't6':31}, {'t1':3, 't2':5, 't3':5, 't4':9}, {'t1':47, 't2':59, 't3':86, 't4':5}]
myks=['t1','t3']
newlist={}
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in list1[i].keys():
        if j in myks:
            if j not in newlist:
                newlist[j] = [list1[i][j]]
            else:
                newlist[j].append(list1[i][j])

print(newlist)

>>> {'t1': [43, 3, 47], 't3': [56, 5, 86]}
```

You can then reference these through list indexing:

```py
print(newlist['t1'][0])
>>> 43
```

Comment: if not dictionary is there any other way to get subset of it??

Comment: @Safney please see the edited answer, you can store all the values you would just need nested lists

Comment: Thanks for quick help